# How transmit python's string to js script

Tags: javascript, python, json, mako

I try to use module json for this, but js script and firebug get errors.
Example. I have this line:

```
{"fruit":{"apple":100}}
```

i try send it to js script called [`jquery.ocupload-1.1.2.js`](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-option-tree/) for build selectors.
And i get what all `"` become `&#34;` and i have an error:

```
'Unexpected token &'
```

And then i try json.dumps its escapes all `"` like `\"` and script dont working with this structs.
How i can make "clean" json struct like `{"fruit":{"apple":100}}` without any escapes and extra characters?

**Solved.** I use Mako for templates. And need switch off filters in it like

```
${my_var | n}
```

http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/filtering.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({"fruit":{"apple":100}})
'{"fruit": {"apple": 100}}'
```

So you are clearly doing something else, which you haven't stated in your question.